# Google Script: How to script an automatic import from a txt in my drive into spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've never used Javascript before and i've been trying for ages to do this but with no luck, and I can't find any previous people trying.
I want to copy the text data straight from this txt document in my drive, it is possible to do this fine manually but I want it to be done daily automatically instead.

The text document;

```js
Boxes Made,3  
Target Percentage,34  
Hourly Rate,2
```

If I import this into a spreadsheet with these settings its perfect;

[Import Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onl3S.jpg)

And it imports like this;

[After Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R93FX.jpg)

Now I need to try and automate this so that a script imports it automatically. 
The script I have so far doesn't work, please help.

Current script;

```js
 function AutoImporter (Source)
{
  var Source = DriveApp.getFilesByName('DailyData.txt');
  var TextContents = Source.copyText();
  var Target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    
  Target.appendText(TextContents[1]);  
  }
```

--edit

Some guy just sent me a script that seems closer but still didn't work;

```js
function autoCSV() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r=s.getActiveCell();
  var id="DailyData.txt";//<<<<<enter the ID of the text file
  var f3=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var lst1=f3.getBlob().getDataAsString().split('\n').map(function(x) {return x.split(',')});
  var ncols=1,i,lst2=[];
  for (i in lst1) {if (lst1[i].length>ncols) ncols=lst1[i].length;}
  for (i=0;i<ncols;i++) lst2.push('');
  for (i in lst1) lst1[i]=lst1[i].concat(lst2.slice(0,lst2.length-lst1[i].length));

  s.getRange(r.getRow(), r.getColumn(), lst1.length, ncols).setValues(lst1);
}
```

Comment: Could you, please, provide two or three rows of `DailyData.txt` verbatim in the question. Paste it as a code snippet.

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may read text file from Google Drive this way:

```
'use strict'; // <- Always use strict mode.

function foo() {

  var fileName = 'DailyData.txt';
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
  if (!files.hasNext()) {
    throw new Error('No file with name:' + fileName);
  }
  // We take only the first file among all files with such name.
  var file = files.next();
  var text = file.getBlob().getDataAsString('utf8');
  Logger.log(text);
  // Now you have to parse the file.

}
```

Documentation:

1. [DriveApp.getFilesByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename) returns collection of `File`s.
2. [File.getBlob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getBlob()) returns `Blob`.
3. [Blob.getDataAsString](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getDataAsString(String)) returns `String`.

Comment: Thanks you so much, thats awesome, how would I parse it, something like this?

Comment: var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r=s.getActiveCell();
  
  s.appendRow(text[r]); @ilyaigpetrov

Comment: Yay I got it working, thank you very much for the help!