# Open file by name, than accessing its inside

Tags: google-apps-script

Below is the code.  The objective is to a. get a list of file names from the starting document, b. open the files on the drive (all spreadsheets). c. access the data store in the named file. d. write the data into the starting file.

I cannot figure out how to do C.

```
  function ListTree() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Raw");
    var name_list = sheet.getRange('file_names').getValues();
    var list_out =       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Listing");
    var i = 0;


    while (name_list[i][0])
    {
    var target_dump = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name_list[i][0]);
    var file_open = target_dump.next();
    var sheeting = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
    logger.log(name_list[i][0]);
    list_out.appendRow([name_list[i][0]]);
    i++;
   };
   };
```

Comment: Do you want to convert opened file to a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Read File as a String

`var text = file_open.getBlob().getDataAsString('utf8');`

See my related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42876241/521957

#### Read File as a Spreadsheet

If you want to open file as a spreadsheet use [SpreadsheetApp.open(file_open)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#open(File))